# Activity class {yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi/yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi.SearchActivity} does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I am developing android app but I am getting following error
when I am running code in the emulator

> error while executing: am start -n
>   "yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi/yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi.SearchActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi/.SearchActivity } Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class
>   {yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi/yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi.SearchActivity}
>   does not exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

below my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi.SearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NextActivity"
            />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

below package structure of my app[image: package structure]

Comment: make sure your activity name i think you added in manifiest is your packagename activity name is which is in your java files name.

Comment: @yuvrajsinh I have added as the same package name

Comment: after doing <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"> in manifiest still gatting same error???

Comment: yes the same error

Comment: try to clean the project go to file and choose invalidate catches and restart

Answer (score 0):

**Replace it**

```
 <activity android:name="yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.githubapi.SearchActivity">
```

**with**

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity">
```

Comment: what name comes on your .java file name like is there name like SearchActivity.java or else?

Comment: can you please show your SearchActivity.java activitys code

Comment: please check it I have put screenshot

Comment: after changes clean and rebuild project then run